# Shopware 6 - Set shopsite only for specific language

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I need a specific shopsite to be active only in a specific language on a multilang shop.

And I am wondering, if there is an option given on the admin-panel/categories or do I need to set it via template?

Answer (score 1):

That's possible with the [`Dynamic Access` plugin](https://store.shopware.com/swag140583558965t/dynamic-access.html), that is part of the Professional and Enterprise editions of shopware.

Comment: Reading the plugin description it seems to be more about limiting pages to certain customer groups. Is it also possible to hide a specific (untranslated) language version of a page completely? Of course it would be interesting to know how this specific function could be implemented without the overhead of a plugin which does much more :-)

Comment: Are you sure this works per-language? And Is the language switcher then removed on such pages or is there a possible to set a fallback page to link to, if content is not available in a certain language? Or does it just show 404 ?